# asp.net c# public statics and concurrent users

Tags: c#, oop, static

I have a MyClassFile.cs file that looks like this:

```
public class MyClass1
{
    public static DataTable ReadData(string Connection, string Command, Dictionary Parameters)
    {
        //ADO.NET stuff here to .Fill() the DataTable Below
        return dtTable;
    }

    public static void WriteData(string Connection, string Command, Dictionary Parameters)
    {
        //ADO.NET stuff to write to DB
    }
}
```

I use it in my Default.aspx.cs like this:

```
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var Parameters = new Dictionary<string, object>
        {
            { "?Parameter1", TextBox1.Text },
            { "?Parameter2", TextBox2.Text }
        };

        DataTable dtTable = MyClass1.ReadData(Connection, Command, Parameters);
        ListView1.DataSource = dtTable;
        ListView1.DataBind();
    }
}
```

This is for a website. Will I run into problems with this code especially since ReadData() is public static? What if there are a lot of users concurrently using it?

My goal is to have a reusable ".ReadData(x,y,z)" and ".WriteData(x,y,z)"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Static methods are inherently threadsafe, as long as they're not accessing objects that are shared by other parts of your application. So in your ReadData/WriteData methods, if you're just accepting parameters, creating a DB connection, executing statements and returning something then you should be OK.

Answer (score 4):

It looks like those methods don't have any shared state - they're not using any static variables - so you should be okay.

I'd personally prefer to have the data layer injected into the presentation layer (or have another layer between) to make testing easier - static methods are often the enemy of testing - but that's a slightly different matter.